# Как изменить фон сайта из расширения

Tags: javascript, html, css

Html

```
  <p>Укажите цвет фона: <input type="color" name="bg" id="color" value="#262626">
  <br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Применить" id="submit" class="clrbtn">`введите сюда код`
```

CSS

```
:root {
    --background-color: #2cba92;
}

html {
  background-size: 100% 100% !important;
  background-color: var(--background-color) !important;
}
```

JS

```
var root = document.querySelector(':root');
var rootStyles = getComputedStyle(root);

const inputs = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('input')); // 2
inputs.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', handleUpdate)); // 4

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
    submit.addEventListener('click', function() {
        root.style.setProperty('--background-color', '#88d8b0');
        alert('Успешно!');
    });
});
```

Требуется, чтоб таким образом менялся фон на сайте (напомню, делается все это в расширении), без его перезагрузки. Но ничего не получается. Что не так?

Comment: `document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'red'`

Answer (score 0):

Это будет работать?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
    submit.addEventListener('click', function() {
        document.body.style.background = document.getElementById('color').value;
    });
});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #2cba92;
}

html {
  background-size: 100% 100% !important;
  background-color: var(--background-color) !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
   <p>Укажите цвет фона: <input type="color" name="bg" id="color" value="#262626">
   <br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Применить" id="submit" class="clrbtn">
</body>
</html>
```